# Multiple RotateTransforms with different origins

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a `UserControl` which needs two `RotateTransform`'s, one to rotate around it's top-left corner (i.e. `(0,0)`) and another to rotate around it's center.

Up until now I only needed it to rotate around the center, and this was easily done by setting the control's `RenderTransformOrigin` to (`0.5,0.5`).

How can I set a different origin for each rotate transform ?

---

Note that I'm also using other transformations (around the center) so I need them all to work together, so I could use a `TransformGroup` to rotate/scale/translate around the center,but I need a separate `RotateTransform` that rotates around the top-left corner only - How would I do that ?

Comment: Do you have two storyboards I understand one per origin, I suppose, and how you animate them by calling the storyboards by code?

Comment: I have one storyboard to apply `RotateTransform` around 0,0 and all the other transforms (rotate/scale/translate) around the center based on `ManipulationDelta`.